# Can HEIF media be streamed?

Tags: ios, streaming, media, hevc, heif

HEIF (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format) seems like a great container to replace many image formats. It can use HEVC for video. But, like video formats, can it be streamed or progressively downloaded? For instance, could a cover image or thumbnail be downloaded first and displayed to the user, while waiting for additional larger resolution images, all via one file?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen from WWDC session about HEIF & HEVC, it is possible to stream **HEVC** video via **HLS**. HEVC can be accessed/consumed using the following methods:

**Excerpt from WWDC: ([Introducing HEIF and HEVC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/503/))**

> **Accessing HEVC**
>   **HEVC movie support**
>   **AVFoundation**--supported media source
>   **PhotoKit**--movies, resources and edit
>   **WebKit**--hardware support and macOS desktops
>   HTTP Live Streaming (**HLS**)
>   Apple apps

But I am not really sure about the progressive download.